# Transforming keys of a map in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I'm working with a REST API that represents an account with the following JSON:

```
{ "userName": "foo", "password": "bar", "emailId": "baz" }
```

I have a Clojure function to create an account that can be called like this:

```
(create-account :username "foo" :password "bar" :email "baz")
```

What I want to do is map the nice keys that `create-account` takes to the funky ones that the REST API expects. My current solution is this:

```
(def clj->rest {:username :userName
                :email :emailId})

(apply hash-map
       (flatten (map
                 (fn [[k v]] [(or (clj->rest k) k) v])
                 args)))  ;; args is the arguments to create-account, as above
```

Is there a more idiomatic way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
(clojure.set/rename-keys args clj->rest)
```

... mimics your solution, producing ...

```
{:emailId "baz", :userName "foo", :password "bar"}
```

I take it you've worked out how to change this into the required JSON.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks! Yes, the JSON is no problem; I could either use `clojure.data.json/write-str` or just use the `{:form-params {...} :content-type :json}` stuff in clj-http.

Answer (score 4):

You may write a simple helper function to map all keys with given mapping function:

```
(defn kmap [f m]
  (into {} (map #(update-in % [0] f) m)))
```

So, now you'll be able to easily map your arguments:

```
(def clj->rest {:username :userName
                :password :password
                :email :emailId})

(kmap clj->rest args)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks good, just change `(apply hash-map (flatten ...` to `(into {} ...` for more idiomatic code.

Answer (score 1):

Since Clojure 1.11, you can use the [update-keys](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/update-keys) function for key transforms, e.g:

```clj
(update-keys {"Content-Type" "text/plain"} str/lower-case)
=> {"content-type" "text/plain"}
```